# systemcalls.h no such file or directory found

Tags: c, unix, system-calls

I am reading C programming by K&R and i just started the last chapter: UNIX SYSTEM INTERFACE. I came across the a filecopy code which makes a system call. First i compiled that code in codeblocks windows i got an error that dir/file not found then i thought i should compile this code in Linux. But i got the same error after than.

I read some other questions on stackoverflow did:
sudo apt-get update 
installed linux header again then

read somewhere that use syscall.h but then BUFSIZ is not defined in that and i don't think this book is wrong.

```c
#include "syscalls.h"

int main()
{
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    int n;
    while((n = read(0, buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0)
    write(1, buf, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
char buf[BUFSIZ];
int n;
while((n = read(0,buf,BUFSIZ))>0)
     write(1,buf,n); //Output to the Console
return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** `unistd.h` can be used. Fixed Typos too!

**Output:**

```
myunix:/u/mahesh> echo "Hi\nWorld" | a.out
Hi
World
```

Comment: is the book wrong why they have used syscalls.h ? confused what to study what not

Comment: Perhaps the book refers to a custom heder that the author created, since the incude is in quoutes, "syscalls.h" , while referring to a system header would normally be in brackets, <syscalls.h>

Comment: It's a pretty old book (the most recent edition was published in 1988). Some of the info might be outdated.

Comment: error: ‘BUFSIZE’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Comment: `BUFSIZE` available in `stdio.h`

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar i included <stdio.h>

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar now this doesn't copy anything as i have passed the std I/O what if i want to copy a file can you edit your code? Please suppose i want to copy text.txt

Comment: @Noobsplzdon't-1 You made a typo copying code from the book. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change `"syscalls.h"` to `<sys/syscall.h>`. This is the proper header in Linux.

Add `#include <stdio.h>` to get `BUFSIZE`.

You also have a couple typos in your code:
-Change `BIFSIZE` to `BUFSIZE` in the while statement. Now it will compile.
-However, you also forgot to assign `n` in the loop. Change to `n = read(`

The final code should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
main()
{
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    int n;
    while((n = read(0,buf,BUFSIZ))>0)
        write(1,buf,n);
    return 0;
}
```